# Show all date outside validarange in fullcalender

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

I am using [fullcalender](https://fullcalendar.io/demos) where I have added validRange property.
After adding user won't be able to navigate outside given daterange also fullcalender will show disable those blocks.

But I want to see Date in those disabled colums.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/amitverma0511/pen/RwjvedO)

calender options:

```
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'dayGrid' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    height: 'auto',
    events: 'https://fullcalendar.io/demo-events.json?overload-day',
    validRange: {
        start: '2021-05-01',
        end: new Date()
    },
  });
```

**Current Output:**
[image]

**Expected Output:**
[image]

Comment: Set the end date of the validRange to the end of the current month, instead of the current date.

Comment: P.S. the correct spelling is `calendar`, not `calender`. (You can see that on the fullcalendar website and in its URL, and in the blue "fullcalendar" tag in your question...) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since you set up the end date with today, so it's normal.

Just remove the `end: new Date()` of `validRange:`.

You can refer to this [codepen](https://codepen.io/halu-chen/pen/eYexQYe).

Good Luck:)

Comment: This not what I want. If I remove end then user will be able to navigate using right arrow button. I don't want user to navigate further but also I just want date in disable cells